# CSS <button> Reset: Vertical Label Position?

Tags: css

I want to completely reset a `button`'s inherited CSS so it behaves exactly like any other inline-block element. However, I've run into a problem where the text of a button is forever stuck vertically-centered.

In the fiddle (and screenshot) below, the `button` and `div` have the **exact same styles** according to the Chrome Developer Console, yet the button's text is vertically-centered, while the div's is not:

http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/vT3a7/

[image: button vs div]

Anyone know of the property or selector that will completely reset a button, specifically including its label position?

---

## Answer

There's no way in any browser other than Chrome ~25. I reached out to the Chromium project about the it not working in Chrome 27 (see the @winterblood answer & comments). They said this:

> The issue is that we now use margin:auto on the anonymous block inside the button to do the centering inside the button in order to get safe-centering. So, unfortunately, there's no way to style it from CSS. That you were able to control this behavior before was really implementation detail leaking out.

So, the true answer is that you cannot style this in any browser, except for Chrome ~25 where `-webkit-box-align` was inadvertently exposed to, as @winterblood answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For webkit you need to override `-webkit-box-align` with a value of `baseline` or `start`.

I have had no luck implementing this in Firefox yet (from a very brief look at it).

Comment: `-moz-box-align: baseline;` should do the trick in firefox. You also probably want to add the standard `box-align: baseline;` for CSS3 compliant browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. Firstly, I've overridden `display` to be `inline-block` which will remove the `display:-webkit-box` functionality. Secondly, at least in Chrome 27 dev, even setting the `box-align` property does not affect the label position (it will affect the `div`, though, when setting `display:-webkit-box` back). Perhaps it's a bug. I've versioned the fiddle to show it not working (in Chrome 27, at least): http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/vT3a7/5/

Comment: @clav `-mox-box-align:baseline` or `:start` did not work for me in a jsFiddle. @rgthree `-webkit-box-align:baseline` works fine for me with `display:inline-block` (in Chrome 25)

Comment: @winterblood Interesting, so the button text is at the top for you in this fiddle (using `-webkit-box-align:start`)? http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/vT3a7/5/ It's not for me in Chrome 27

Comment: @rgthree Yes the text is aligned at the top of the button in both Chrome 25 and Iron 23. I am assuming it may be an issue specific to 27, but whether that will be the standard in future versions is an unknown.

Comment: @winterblood Yeah. I assume since `box-align` is the old flex-box syntax they must be removing it. Unfortunately, the new flex-box styles don't seem to affect (I actually created a bug http://goo.gl/2tDqA). I'm going to leave this open for a bit to see if I can get a more cross-browser fix, but you may have the only viable answer.

Comment: I battle tested other ways in FireFox & IE but found no way to style the button. I heard back from Chromium and found out that @winterblood's answer is the only viable one, through an inadvertent exposure in Chrome ~25. It won't work in later Chrome versions or other browsers. I updated the post to reflect what Chromium mentioned.